# Imagemagick can't convert large tif files to jpg

Tags: php, imagemagick, filesize

I'm sending an .tif Image via POST to a .php file which should convert the image into a *.jpg and return it.

This is the content of the convert.php

```
file_put_contents("tmp.tif", base64_decode($_POST["file"]));

if(isset($_POST["file"])){
    system("convert tmp.tif tmp.jpg");
    echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("tmp.jpg"));
}
```

Now this work's quite well, but for some reason, if I try to convert files with a size of 6MB or more, the "tmp.tif" will be empty.

I tried playing around with the "-quality" "-resize" and the "-limit memory" parameter, but nothing seems to work. I don't get any errors as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible the php `post_max_size` size isn't enough, have you tried using `file_put_contents` with a `6MB+` file and *not* converting it?

Comment: Sadly I can't look into the php file at the moment. I'll have a word with the server-administrator asap. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to "l'L'l"
The Problem was indeed that the post_max_size wasn't large enough